# How to retry nested for loop if exception occurs?

Tags: python, python-requests

When exception occurs it skips the current "y". I can't manage to prevent this.

```
  for x in range(1, 100):
            for y in range(1, 100):
                try:
                    text = requests.post(url, {"x":a, "y":b})
                except:
                    time.sleep(10)
```

solved with while True but now it doesnt break the first loop

Comment: Make it a function and have the exception call the function again.

Comment: @tgikal that restarts the process and it's not what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the `try`/`except` block in a loop and include a `break` statement at the end of the `try` block. Your program will continue to try to make the post request until it succeeds and reaches the `break`. If `requests.post` encounters an exception, the program will skip the `break` and move to the `except` block, wait, then try again.

For example:

```
for x in range(1, 100):
    for y in range(1, 100):
        while True:
            try:
                text = requests.post(url, {"x":a, "y":b})
                break
            except:
                time.sleep(10)
```

**Edit**

Since you mentioned that for each `x`, the program should try each `y` until finding the correct `y`, at which point the program should skip to the next `x`, I've added this update. To do this, you can keep a variable to track if the correct `y` has been found yet. Then after each `y` is tried, you can check the value of this variable (`found_correct_y`) and if it is `True`, break out of the `for y in ...` loop and on to the next value of `x`.

Here's an example:

```
for x in range(1, 100):
    found_correct_y = False
    for y in range(1, 100):
        while True:
            try:
                response = requests.post(url, {"x":a, "y":b})
                found_correct_y = was_correct_y(response)
                break # out of the 'while True' loop
            except: 
                time.sleep(10)
        if found_correct_y:
            break # out of the 'for y ...' loop, to the next x


def was_correct_y(response):
    """returns a boolean based on some properties of the response"""
    pass
```

Comment: it solved the problem but now it doesnt break the first loop and keeps trying with the same x

Comment: @kusky can you explain a bit more? Do you want it to try again with a different x if an exception is thrown?

Comment: for every x it tries all the 100 y but if it finds the correct y it should go to the next x

Comment: @kusky made an edit, let me know if that helps

Comment: name 'response' is not defined, theres some much code in the for loop i lost my mind. i accepted the answer tho because it seems like it would work

Comment: @kusky I renamed `text` to `response` because it's a more accurate name, you can get the text by doing `response.text`. Also because figuring out the correct `y` might depend on something other than just the response text, like status codes. Hope you can get it working though. Let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 1):

I raised an exception in the inner 'y' block and still had success, ie looping back to the 'x' block.

```
for x in range(1, 10):
            for y in range(1, 10):
                try:
                    #text = requests.post(url, {"x":a, "y":b})
                    print('y',y,'x',x)
                    if (x==2):
                        raise
                except:
                    time.sleep(10)
```